# can an instance of pilot configured to query both k8s and consul?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, consul, istio

we run services in k8s and non-k8s. Non-k8s services are registered in Consul. We are thinking of adding istio in our stack, and we, ideally, want k8s services to call non-k8s services. So, I have few questions about that

1) Does a single instance of Pilot support query both k8s and consul?
2) Can istio be configured to support such environment?

I tried reading up istio docs but can't find if Pilot can be configured to query both consul and k8s together. Reference links to docs/blogs would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Kubernetes v1.6, **kube-dns** supports configuration for the [custom dns zones](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/04/configuring-private-dns-zones-upstream-nameservers-kubernetes/) (for example, `.consul.local`) with an external resolver, and for the external DNS servers for serving requests to the "other zones”.

To use this feature, two things should be configured properly:

1. Add the custom zones to kube-dns ConfigMap
2. Set the pod [dnsPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) to the ClusterFirst value 
   (search for details in section "Pod’s DNS Policy" of the linked document)

> With the dnsPolicy set to “ClusterFirst” a DNS query is first sent to
>   the DNS caching layer in kube-dns. From here, the suffix of the
>   request is examined and then forwarded to the appropriate DNS. In this
>   case, names with the cluster suffix (e.g.; “.cluster.local”) are sent
>   to kube-dns. Names with the stub domain suffix (e.g.; “.acme.local”)
>   will be sent to the configured custom resolver. Finally, requests that
>   do not match any of those suffixes will be forwarded to the upstream
>   DNS.

Here is an example of adding custom map for zone `.consul.local` and custom upstream services.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  stubDomains: |
    {“consul.local”: [“10.150.0.1”]}
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
```

To apply this configuration, save it to file `kube-dns-consul-stubdomain.yml` and run the command (adjust the zone name and the server IP according to your needs):

```
kubectl create -f kube-dns-consul-stubdomain.yml
```

This is an example of pod configuration with dnsPolicy

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
  hostNetwork: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
```

You can find these resources helpful to understand the details of Private DNS Zones feature:

- [Kubernetes - Exposing External Services to Pods via Consul](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/virtualization/Kubernetes-exposing-external-services-to-Pods-via-Consul/)
- [Customizing DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/)
- [consul-dns-for-kubernetes](https://github.com/anubhavmishra/consul-dns-for-kubernetes#consul-dns-for-kubernetes)

Comment: Thanks VAS for taking a stab at it! One of the challenges with using DNS is that most services/proxies in our stack don't yet support SRV DNS record.